# Regarding timer_create (memory leak)

Tags: c, linux, timer

I am working on a memory leak tool, the thing is: this tool should catch memory leaks only from test program, but what actually happens is, i have created a timer using API timer_create (POSIX), and this is somehow causing a leak of 144+56 bytes.

Any idea, as to how to stop it? How can i make sure, that all malloc requests from timer_create are not logged?

**I am using the timer thread function method, and not signal. SIGEV_THREAD**

Comment: Did you know that there's already `valgrind` to detect memory leaks?

Comment: Can it detect memory leak on ARM and mips target?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: There is perhaps a bigger world, than the desktop, so please don't limit your thinking only to the x86 (the old Desktop) :-)

Comment: @kingsmaster1: Does the memory leak happen at each timer_create or only the first time? Some runtimes are used to do some dynamic allocations in a "lazy" way. In your case, the "timer" subsystem may allocate something at the first access, and it's intepreted as a "leak" by the checker. Bye!

Comment: @kingsmaster1: `valgrind` supports ARM, but not mips (http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html). There's a lot of MIPs tools suggested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906228/how-to-profile-memory-usage-of-a-c-program

Comment: @Adrian: That won't serve our purpose, we use our own proprietory tools.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `N` in your reported memory leakage, just what appears to be a small constant, so my initial guess is that this is purely one-time overhead of setting up the timer thread system and not an actual memory leak. Try running your program with `strace` and make sure the timer is destroyed. If so, whatever internal memory is left is a matter of the implementation's quality and not a potential error in your program.

By the way, another good test approach: create 10 or 100 timers, then destroy them all, and compare the amount of memory "leaked". If it's the same as with one, I would say there's no issue.